# Connect to running Python pdb from code buffer

Tags: python, debugging

How can I connect the standard Emacs programming debugger (is this GUD? I don't know) to the running Python application's debugger?

When developing large Python applications, the Python `pdb` debugger is invoked by running the full application in debug mode. This also allows a remote connection.

How can I tell Emacs that there's a running instance of the application, it allows debugging via `pdb`, here's the PIN to authenticate, and please sync the code buffers and let me set breakpoints, step through, etc. using Emacs-provided debugging tools?

Comment: Are you using GUD, or do you want to just run a shell in Emacs where you can send commands to PDB?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about built in solutions, but I suggest you to try realgud: https://github.com/realgud/realgud. It's absolute gold in my opinion and it works with both pdb and ipdb.